# Rails validations: count associations excluding objects to be deleted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a model that looks like this:

```
class thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bobbles

  validate :has_two_bobbles
  def has_two_bobbles
    unless self.bobbles.size == 2
      errors.add(:bobbles, "Need two bobbles")
    end
  end
end
```

I'm running in to trouble when updating from a form. If I delete a bobble and add a bobble in the same submission, when I hit self.bobbles.size I get 3 and not 2. Is there anywhere to restrict self.bobbles to return only the records that arent's scheduled for deletion?

I know in the controller you have access to _destroy in the params, but is there anything at the model level that indicates if a record is going to be deleted?

Comment: In short no! Can you show us the controller action so we can see how you are deleting and adding bobbles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Record is going to die when it responded to `.marked_for_destruction?`

```
class thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bobbles

  validate :has_two_bobbles
  def has_two_bobbles
    unless self.bobbles.select {|t| !t.marked_for_destruction?}.size == 2
      errors.add(:bobbles, "Need two bobbles")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I knew there was a method that kept track of this, thanks for the reminder!